# 配列の中のハッシュをidごとに値を合計した上で一つにまとめたい

Tags: ruby

以下の処理を`ruby`で行いたいのですが、やり方がわからず困っています。

複数の`[]`から`{}`を取り出し、ひとつの`[]`に格納する。ただし、同じ`id`をもつ`{}`は`num`を合計して一つにまとめる。

```
data1 = [{
  'id' => 1,
  'num' => 1
},{
  'id' => 2,
  'num' => 3
},{
  'id' => 3,
  'num' => 5
}]

data2 = [{
  'id' => 1,
  'num' => 2
},{
  'id' => 3,
  'num' => 4
}]

data3 = [{
  'id' => 1,
  'num' => 2
},{
  'id' => 4,
  'num' => 4
}]
```

↓

```
[{
  'id' => 1,
  'num' => 5
},{
  'id' => 2,
  'num' => 3
},{
  'id' => 3,
  'num' => 9
},{
  'id' => 4,
  'num' => 4
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```ruby
[data1, data2, data3].flatten.each_with_object([]) {|v, a|
  if ev = a.detect { |ev| v['id'] == ev['id'] }
    ev.merge!(v.merge('num' => v['num'] + ev['num']))
  else
    a << v.dup
  end
}
```

質問内容のコード例ではハッシュのキーは`id`と`num`だけでしたが、
ハッシュのキーに`id`、`num`以外が含まれているか書かれていなかったのと、
質問内容の以下の文で

> ただし、同じidをもつ{}はnumを合計して一つにまとめる。

`num`を合計して一つに「まとめる」と書いてあったので、

```ruby
data1 = [{
  'id' => 1,
  'num' => 1,
  'foo' => 'bar'
},{
  'id' => 2,
  'num' => 3
},{
  'id' => 3,
  'num' => 5
}]

data2 = [{
  'id' => 1,
  'num' => 2,
  'bar' => 'buzz'
},{
  'id' => 3,
  'num' => 4
}]

data3 = [{
  'id' => 1,
  'num' => 2,
  'hoge' => 'piyo'
},{
  'id' => 4,
  'num' => 4
}]

# => [{"id"=>1, "num"=>5, "foo"=>"bar", "bar"=>"buzz", "hoge"=>"piyo"}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>3}, {"id"=>3, "num"=>9}, {"id"=>4, "num"=>4}]
```

上記のようなデータが入力されたときのことを考えてコードを書きました。

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [data1, data2, data3].flatten.group_by { |elem| elem['id'] }

result_data = []
data.each_pair do |key, arr|
  sum = arr.inject(0) { |memo, item| memo + item['num'] }
  result_data << { 'id' => key, 'num' => sum }
end

p result_data
```

まずは、複数の配列を一つにまとめて、idごとに分類します。
次に、分類されたそれぞれのグループの要素のnumの総和を求めます。
最後に、結果を`result_data`に格納します。

Comment: [data1, data2, data2]は[data1, data2, data3]のtypoですか?

Comment: 修正しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じで、どうでしょう？一度、Hashにしてから、配列に戻しています。

```
[data1, data2, data3].flatten.inject Hash.new do |a,e|
  h = { e['id'] => e['num'] }
  a.merge! h do |k, v1, v2|
    v1 + v2
  end
end.inject [] do |a,e|
  a << { 'id' => e[0], 'num' => e[1] }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

ハッシュのキーがidとnumだけであれば

```ruby
[data1, data2, data3].flatten.each_with_object({}) { |v, r|
  r[v['id']] ||= 0
  r[v['id']] += v['num']
}.map { |id, num|
  {'id' => id, 'num' => num}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

一時変数を使わずに書いてみました。

```
(data1 + data2 + data3)
  .group_by {|h| h['id'] }
  .reduce([]) {|memo, (k, v)|
    memo << {'id' => k, 'num' => v.map {|h| h['num'] }.reduce(:+) } }
```

Answer (score 1):

面白そうなので僕もやってみました。
ちょっと関数型プログラミングっぽいロジックになってます。

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

def merge_hash(*data_list)
  data_list
    .flatten
    .map(&:values)
    .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(id, num), hash| hash[id] += num }
    .map { |id, num| { 'id' => id, 'num' => num } }
end

describe '#merge_hash' do
  let(:data1) do
    [{
         'id' => 1,
         'num' => 1
     },{
         'id' => 2,
         'num' => 3
     },{
         'id' => 3,
         'num' => 5
     }]
  end
  let(:data2) do
    [{
         'id' => 1,
         'num' => 2
     },{
         'id' => 3,
         'num' => 4
     }]
  end
  let(:data3) do
    [{
         'id' => 1,
         'num' => 2
     },{
         'id' => 4,
         'num' => 4
     }]
  end
  let (:result) do
    [{
         'id' => 1,
         'num' => 5
     },{
         'id' => 2,
         'num' => 3
     },{
         'id' => 3,
         'num' => 9
     },{
         'id' => 4,
         'num' => 4
     }]
  end
  it do
    merge_hash(data1, data2, data3).must_equal result
  end
end
```

こんなやり方もあります。

```
def merge_hash(*data_list)
  data_list
    .flatten
    .map(&:values)
    .group_by(&:first)
    .map{|id, items| { 'id' => id, 'num' => items.map(&:last).inject(:+) } }
end
```